# MySQLi Syntax Error (PHP) on INSERT using Variables

Tags: php, mysql

I am attempting to insert some user-inputted data into my MySQL table using the following command:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO Queued ('$role') VALUES ('$sname')";
```

Interestingly enough, I get the following error:

> Error: INSERT INTO Queued ('Tops') VALUES ('Summoner')
>       You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ''Tops') VALUES ('Summoner')' at line 1

To be honest, I am relatively new at using PHP as well as MySQL, but I can't seem to find the error in my syntax; the Queued table does exist, `$role` and `$sname` are both strings so I encased them in single quotes.  I suspect this is a newbie mistake, could anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Use `INSERT INTO Queued ($role)`, but better yet, use a prepared statement.

Comment: Ah, thanks that fixed the problem.  Why do I need to exclude single quotes around $role but not $sname? Aren't they both interpreted as strings?

Comment: Yes, they are both interpreted as strings, but that happens with or without single quotes.  Column names don't take single quotes in MySQL (or really in any other database).

Comment: Ah gotcha, thanks for the explanation!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When to use single quotes, double quotes, and back ticks in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11321491/when-to-use-single-quotes-double-quotes-and-back-ticks-in-mysql)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is due to use of single quotes `'` around the column name. The query should be like:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO Queued ($role) VALUES ('$sname')";
```

OR

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO Queued (`$role`) VALUES ('$sname')";
```

Comment: What is the role of the `s around $role? Interpret this as non-SQL?

Comment: The OP should be using a statement, and this isn't the best answer which can be given.  Also, backticks around `$role` aren't needed.

Comment: ` are usually used around column names in mysql query.

Answer (score 0):

Try this format

`$sql = "INSERT INTO Queued ('".$role."') VALUES ('".$sname."')";`

Answer (score 0):

`s role is to differentiate between built in SQL words and the column names, so if a word is used for name of a column that might be also a built in sql expression then `` are needed around it